# can't apply colour shade to Color datatype in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a widget for prouducttile and it has required field 'color' and here I want to apply shade like Colors.blue[40] but it does not work

and another question is what should be it's datatype if I pass
Colors.blue[20] to my custom widget

how to solve

```
class ProductTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final bool isfav;
  final String imageurl;
  final Color color;

  const ProductTile({Key? key,required this.name,required this.isfav,required this.color,required this.imageurl,required this.price}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color[50],//showing an error
      child: Center(child: Text(name),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use to Material Color

```
 final MaterialColor color;
```